# Оптимизировать код или как выделить всю вычислительную мощность пк на его выполнение?

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм, оптимизация

Есть массив целых. Задача:

Представить все значения как диапазоны: значение .. (значение + 50)
Взять первое значение (диапазон)
отсечь все пересекающиеся с ним диапазоны ниже
взять второе
отсечь пересекающиеся
следующий
и так далее

Сохранение порядка обязательно.

Код:

```
<?php
$arr = [100,125,75,175,25,300,275,325,375];
$step = 50;

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($arr)-1; $i++) {
    $value = $arr[$i];
    $arr = array_values(array_filter($arr, function($v) use ($value,$step) {
        return ($value+$step < $v or $v+$step < $value or $v == $value);
    }));
}

var_dump($arr); // [100, 175, 25, 300, 375]
?>
```

100к чисел этим кодом обрабатывать сутки.
Перебирать без функций "вручную"?
Или что ещё можно сделать?

Comment: Начать с сортировки. А затем в один проход выполнить задачу. Или порядок тоже имеет значение?

Comment: Да, порядок обязателен

Comment: Значит, добавить к элементам ещё и порядковый номер, а затем сортировать в обратном порядке. *отсечь все пересекающиеся с ним диапазоны ниже* Вот это поясните. Если исходно [100, 140, 180, 220, 260] - что должно остаться? И отдельно - что в данном случае "отсечь"?

Comment: Зависит от шага. Мой код с шагом в 50 оставил [100, 180, 260]

Comment: Ну, диапазон 100-150 пересекается с 125-175 и с 75-125, но не пересекается с 175-225. То есть среди всех пересекающихся диапазонов в массиве нужно оставить только самые верхние. Отсечь - значит удалить (желательно не оставляя пустого места)

Comment: "среди всех пересекающихся диапазонов в массиве нужно оставить только самые верхние" получается что сортировка тут помешает

Comment: Подумай над следующим. Дополняем элементы исходным номером. Сортируем по элементу. Далее пробегаем по сортированному набору, перебирая пары, и в случае пересечения по значению удаляем элемент, имеющий бОльший исходный номер. Потом сортируем уже по номеру, и номера удаляем. Навскидку я не могу понять, получится ли тот же результат, или возможны косяки - то есть на первый взгляд варианта, дающего косяк, я не нашёл, но это не доказательство.

Comment: подумал, но не могу понять, надо пробовать

Comment: так а что бы тупо выделить больше вычислительной мощности под задачу - это другой язык нужен?

Comment: Погонял практически (правда, на VBA, и не заморачиваясь на эффективную сортировку) - ни разу не получил различных результатов "влоб" и по описанному алгоритму.

Comment: Раз диапазон `50`, то и переменную `$i` нужно прибавлять на `50`, а не `++$i`.